# How to handle return values in async function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, restsharp

When working on data APIs which use async rest calls (I am using RestSharp.Portable), what is the best way to handle return values? Since async function can only return a Task or Task ... but the caller has no way to getting back to the return value ... how would the API return data back to the caller? Global properties?

From what I have read so far, it appears that callback functions are the only way to interact with Response Data?

Take the following method for example; previously I was not using async Rest library and was able to return a value but after converting it to use RestSharp.Portable, I dont see a way to return the value:

```
public async Task<EntityResourceDescriptor> GetEntityDescriptor(string entityType)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<EntityResourceDescriptor> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<EntityResourceDescriptor>();
        var req = new RestRequest("/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/customization/entities/{entityType}");
        AddDomainAndProject(req);
        req.AddParameter("entityType", entityType, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        client.ExecuteAsync<EntityResourceDescriptor>(req, (res) =>
            {
                if (res.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Error)
                {
                    tcs.TrySetException(res.ErrorException);
                }
                else
                {
                    tcs.SetResult(res.Data);
                }
            }
        );
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Here all I can do is return Task but the caller still has no way to get to the response data or am I missing something obvious? Can the caller subscribe to an event which gets fired at Task.Completed etc.?

I am very fuzzy on this async concept. Are there any examples of writing Portable data APIs?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You're setting the task's result. That data will be returned to the caller when the task is complete.

Comment: Not really, because the method exits immediately after sending the client.ExecuteAsync. Whereas tcs.Task doesnt provide a direct way to interact with the value. When I add 'await' keyword (to force the method execution to complete before exiting) I started getting compiler errors which were specific to RestSharp.Portable exe and didn't really make much sense to me. I will go through the article suggested by @sstan and see if the errors will make sense or not. I am probably missing something obvious in my implementation. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll really need to take a step back and read about how to use the `async` and `await` keywords. Among other things, you'll need to understand some of the compiler magic that happens behind the scenes when coding `async` methods.

Here is a good place to start: [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

More to your question, the [Return Types and Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_ReturnTypesandParameters) section has this to say:

> You specify `Task<TResult>` as the return type if the method contains a `Return` (Visual Basic) or `return` (C#) statement that specifies an operand of type **TResult**.

It then gives the following code example:

```
// Signature specifies Task<TResult>
async Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync()
{
    int hours;
    // . . .
    // Return statement specifies an integer result.
    return hours;
}
```

Notice how despite the method return type of `Task<int>`, the `return` statement simply returns an `int`, not a `Task<int>`.  That's basically because there is some compiler magic going on that makes this legal only in `async` methods.

Without wanting to get into all the details, you should also know that the caller of the `async` method is normally expected to do so using the `await` keyword, which knows how to deal with the `Task` or `Task<TResult>` return values and automatically unwraps the actual expected return value for you in a transparent manner (more compiler magic behind the scenes).

So for the above example, here is one way to call it:

```
int intValue = await TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync(); // Task<int> is automatically unwrapped to an int by the await keyword when the async method completes.
```

Or, if you wish to start the async method, perform some other work in the meantime, and then wait for the async method to complete, this can be done like this:

```
Task<int> t = TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync();
// perform other work here
int intValue = await t; // wait for TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync to complete before continuing.
```

Hopefully this gives you a general idea of how to pass values back from an async method.

For your specific example, I am not familiar with RestSharp (never used it).  But from what little I read, I think you'll want to use `client.ExecuteTaskAsync<T>(request)` instead of `client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, callback)` to better fit in the `async-await` model.

I'm thinking your method would instead look something like this:

```
public async Task<EntityResourceDescriptor> GetEntityDescriptor(string entityType)
{
    var req = new RestRequest("/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/customization/entities/{entityType}");
    AddDomainAndProject(req);
    req.AddParameter("entityType", entityType, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    var res = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<EntityResourceDescriptor>(req);

    if (res.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Error)
    {
        throw new Exception("rethrowing", res.ErrorException);
    }
    else
    {
        return res.Data;
    }
}
```

Your calling code would then look like this:

```
EntityResourceDescriptor erd = await GetEntityDescriptor("entityType");
```

I hope you manage to get this working.  But again, make sure to read the documentation about the `async-await` style of programming.  It's very neat once you wrap your head around the compiler magic that is done for you.  But it's so easy to get lost if you don't take the time to really understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that article. I will try your suggestion and see if I can make sense of it all.