# async Task<TResult> - Return Value

Tags: c#

How to return data from a method using "`async Task<string>`".
I tried to use as per the following link,
[How to handle return values in async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496755/how-to-handle-return-values-in-async-function?rq=1)

Could anyone please provide an answer?

---

Method used,

```
Public Class module
{
      private static async Task<string> a<T>(string x1, object file1)
      {
            HttpResponseMessage x;
            x = await b.doGet(function);
            string ret = await x.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return ret; //JSON Data
      }
}
```

Calling,

```
public string get()
{
      Task<string> cnt = module.a<string>(x, file());
      MessageBox.Show(cnt.Result); // Loading, but not showing the result
}
```

---

Thanks
Dinesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your signature is correct, and return `Task<string>`

The deal is when you call `a`, you have two ways to get `string` :

```
public string get()    // For option 2 say public async Task<string> get() 
{
    //Option 1 - Using Task<string>
    Task<string> cnt = module.a<string>(x, file()); // or var cnt = ...
    MessageBox.Show(cnt.GetAwaiter().GetResult()); // Return the string you want

    //Option 2 - Using await
    MessageBox.Show(await module.a<string>(x, file())); // Return the string you want
}
```